# Is it possible to load a background image before video loads?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a YouTube video background on my website and it seems to be taking longer than I'd like to load. To bypass this, I'd like to add a background image to display behind the video until it loads.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<section class="small-background-section">
    <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}"></a>

    <div class="pattern"></div> 
    <div class="small-background-container">
        <center>
            <img src="images/NewLogo.png" style='width:50%;max-width: 300px;padding:0px;'>
        </center>
    </div>                                                    
</section>
```

CSS:

```
    /*
Tutorial Name: Modernize Your Site: Building a YouTube Video Background 
Author: Samuel Dalusung
*/


/* GENERAL STYLES
================================================== */
html {
    height:100%
}

body {
    font:15px/23px 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%
}


p {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:140%;
    text-align:center
}


ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    z-index:600;
    position:relative
}

.pattern {
    background-image:url(../images/pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}

.divider {
    background-image:url(../images/divider.png);
    display:block;

        width:300px;
        height:35px;
        margin:10px auto
    }


    #colorize {
        color:#f1c40f;
        font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
        font-size:40px
    }



    /* BIG VIDEO BACKGROUND
    ================================================== */
    .big-background {
        z-index:550;
        text-align:center;
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden
    }

    .big-background .big-background-container {
        width:830px;
        max-width:100%;
        display:inline-block;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
    }

    .big-background-title {
        font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
        font-size:78px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:300;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:22px;
        padding-top:20px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-attachment:scroll;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-position:top center
    }

    a.big-background-btn {
        font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#fff;
        background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #fff;
        padding:10px 14px;
        cursor:pointer;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        -webkit-transition:.4s background ease;
        -moz-transition:.4s background ease;
        -o-transition:.4s background ease;
        transition:.4s background ease;
    }

    .big-background-btn:hover {
        color:#fff;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0.20)
    }

    .big-background-default-image {
        background:url(../images/sunset.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        background-size:cover;
        width:100%;
        height:25%;
        z-index:0;
        backface-visibility:hidden
    }



    /* ABOUT SECTION
    ================================================== */
    .about-section {
        font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
        color:#7f8c8d;
        background:#fff;
        padding:60px 20px
    }

    .about-section-container {
        text-align:center;
        padding-bottom:50px
    }

    .about-section-title {
        font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
        font-size:40px;
        background:#fff;
        color:#3d566e;
        padding:0 35px;
        margin-bottom:22px;
        background-attachment:scroll;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-position:center center;
        text-transform:uppercase
    }



    a.about-section-btn {
        font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#34495e;
        background:transparent;
        border:2px solid #34495e;
        padding:10px 14px;
        cursor:pointer;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        -webkit-transition:.4s background ease;
        -moz-transition:.4s background ease;
        -o-transition:.4s background ease;
        transition:.4s background ease;
    }

    .about-section-btn:hover {
        color:#fff;
        background: #34495e;
    }



    /* SMALL VIDEO BACKGROUND 
    ================================================== */
    .small-background-section {
        font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
        padding:100px 0;
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden
    }

    .small-background-container {
        position:relative;
        text-align:center
    }

    .small-background-title {
        font-size:40px;
        color:#f1c40f;
        font-weight:300;
        z-index:10;
        display:inline-block;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position:relative;
        background-attachment:scroll;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-position:top center
    }



    /* SOCIALS
    ================================================== */
    .socials a {
        color:#fff
    }

    .socials a:hover {
        color:#bdc3c7
    }


    nav.demo-nav {
        width:350px;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block
    }

    /* NAVIGATION BAR
    ================================================== */

    navi.main-nav {
        background:#fff;
        height:60px;
        z-index:170;
        margin:0 auto;
        border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* MEDIA QUERIES
    ================================================== */

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .about-section-title {
        line-height:1
    }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .big-background-title {
        font-size:58px
    }

    .small-background-title {
        line-height:1
    }

    /*.player{ display: none;}  -> If you want to remove the video bg on a specific viewport w/o plugin*/
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .big-background-title,#colorize {
        line-height:1
    }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .small-background-title {
        font-size:30px
    }
    }
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You may set a default image to the container where the video load, When the video start loading it will l be override the image. i think this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- Unfortunately the default image only works when it's on mobile and can't display video.

Comment: I see you've got some parameters being set in `data-property` can you set  something like `poster: poster.png`? See [HTML5 video element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) on MDN for the details...